# Is there a way to get the Future from setMethodCallHandler?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `setMethodCallHandler` which runs a callback from my Java code, and I want it to set a Future containing the result. Something like

```
Future<String> fun() async {

  return setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) {
    return () async {return call.arguments["arg"];}();
  });
}
```

What I want to be able to do is if call.argument will return "abc",

```
var a = await fun();
```

`a` will be equal to "abc"

The only information I found was the documentation on `setMethodCallHandler`:

> If the future returned by the handler completes with a result, that value is sent back to the platform plugin caller wrapped in a success envelope as defined by the codec of this channel. If the future completes with a PlatformException, the fields of that exception will be used to populate an error envelope which is sent back instead.

But I don't understand how can I get the "platform plugin caller wrapped in a success envelope as defined by the codec of this channel"?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? What are you trying to accomplish? In what context are you using `setMethodCallHandler`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is that any clearer?

Comment: Not really. `setMethodCallHandler` is a method of `MethodChannel` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMethodCallHandler.html (where you copied the citation from) but you code declares a new `setMethodCallHandler` function that seems unrelated to `MethodChannel`. To me it's not clear what the purpose of the code in your question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing, but correct me if I'm wrong, that `setMethodCallHandler` does not return a value, it only sets up a function to be called later.
So, you can't use the return value of the `setMethodCallHandler` for anything.

That effectively means that you have an "event" of a kind, one that you want to "convert" into a future completion. To do that, you use a `Completer` to create and later complete a `Future`.

```dart
Future<String> fun() {
  var completer = new Completer<String>();
  setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) {
    completer.complete(call.arguments["arg"]);
  }
  return completer.future;
}
```

Using `async` functions works when your events all come from futures or streams, but when you get other kinds of events (like port events, I/O callbacks or timers) and you want to map that back to future/stream events, you use either a `Completer` to complete a future or a `StreamController` to add events to a stream.